# Invalid sql statement error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wrinting subquery with the below query but I am getting error as

> Invalid sql statement error

I don't know what is wrong here

```
select enq.followup_sr_no ColFolSrno,case when enq.followup_sr_no=(select max(followup_sr_no) from  xxcus.XXACL_PN_ENQUIRY_FOLLOWUP where cef_mkey=enq.cef_mkey) and enq.activity_id not in (80,40) then 'Edit' else 'View' end ColViewEdit,

ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID ColFolTypeId,FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE ColFolType,ENQ.PRIORITY_ID ColPrioId,PRI.PRIORITY ColPriority,
to_char(ENQ.FOLLOWUP_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') ColFolUpDt,ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID ColActId,ACT.ACTIVITY ColActivity,ENQ.REMARKS ColComments,

'Flat-' || (select FP.FLAT_NO FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_ratecard rc, xxcus.xxacl_pn_flatproj_v fp where RC.FLAT_ID=FP.FLAT_ID and RC.CEF_MKEY=enq.CEF_MKEY and RC.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO=enq.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO )  ColPrint, 

to_char(ENQ.NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') ColNxtFolUpDt,ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID ColNxtActId,NACT.ACTIVITY ColNxtActivity, (select RC.FLAT_ID FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_ratecard rc where RC.CEF_MKEY=enq.CEF_MKEY and RC.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO=enq.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO)FLAT_ID ,

enq.mkey  mkey , enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY AttendedByMkey , em.user_id User_Id , em.login_name EnqueryBy

from XXACL_PN_EMPLOYEE_ALL_V em, xxcus.XXACL_PN_ENQUIRY_FOLLOWUP enq, xxcus.XXACL_PN_FOLLOWUP_TYPE_V fol,xxcus.XXACL_PN_PRIORITY_V pri,xxcus.XXACL_PN_ACTIVITY_V act,xxcus.XXACL_PN_ACTIVITY_V nact, xxcus.xxacl_pn_flatproj_v flt 

where  ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID = FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE_ID(+) and ENQ.PRIORITY_ID = PRI.PRIORITY_ID(+) and ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID = ACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) and ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID = NACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) AND enq.flat_id = flt.flat_id(+) and enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY = em.USER_ID(+) and  and cef_mkey=2590  order by enq.followup_sr_no desc
```

Comment: Start formatting it properly you will probably see the error then

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sure sir, any tips on how to format the query ? specially: `SQL` and `Oracle` queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `AND` at the very last line: `and  and cef_mkey=2590`. Remove one, it's invalid syntax.

```
select enq.followup_sr_no ColFolSrno,case when enq.followup_sr_no=(select max(followup_sr_no) from  xxcus.XXACL_PN_ENQUIRY_FOLLOWUP where cef_mkey=enq.cef_mkey) and enq.activity_id not in (80,40) then 'Edit' else 'View' end ColViewEdit,
ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID ColFolTypeId,FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE ColFolType,ENQ.PRIORITY_ID ColPrioId,PRI.PRIORITY ColPriority,
to_char(ENQ.FOLLOWUP_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') ColFolUpDt,ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID ColActId,ACT.ACTIVITY ColActivity,ENQ.REMARKS ColComments,
'Flat-' || (select FP.FLAT_NO FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_ratecard rc, xxcus.xxacl_pn_flatproj_v fp where RC.FLAT_ID=FP.FLAT_ID and RC.CEF_MKEY=enq.CEF_MKEY and RC.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO=enq.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO )  ColPrint, 
to_char(ENQ.NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') ColNxtFolUpDt,ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID ColNxtActId,NACT.ACTIVITY ColNxtActivity, (select RC.FLAT_ID FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_ratecard rc where RC.CEF_MKEY=enq.CEF_MKEY and RC.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO=enq.FOLLOWUP_SR_NO)FLAT_ID ,
enq.mkey  mkey , enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY AttendedByMkey , em.user_id User_Id , em.login_name EnqueryBy
from XXACL_PN_EMPLOYEE_ALL_V em, xxcus.XXACL_PN_ENQUIRY_FOLLOWUP enq, xxcus.XXACL_PN_FOLLOWUP_TYPE_V fol,xxcus.XXACL_PN_PRIORITY_V pri,xxcus.XXACL_PN_ACTIVITY_V act,xxcus.XXACL_PN_ACTIVITY_V nact, xxcus.xxacl_pn_flatproj_v flt 
where  ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID = FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE_ID(+) and ENQ.PRIORITY_ID = PRI.PRIORITY_ID(+) and ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID = ACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) and ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID = NACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) AND enq.flat_id = flt.flat_id(+) and enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY = em.USER_ID(+) and  cef_mkey=2590  order by enq.followup_sr_no desc
```

Comment: i didn't got you, wheter to add or remove those things??. What if I want both?

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of query you have

```
where  ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID = FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE_ID(+) and ENQ.PRIORITY_ID = PRI.PRIORITY_ID(+) and ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID = ACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) and ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID = NACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) AND enq.flat_id = flt.flat_id(+) and enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY = em.USER_ID(+) and  and cef_mkey=2590  order by enq.followup_sr_no desc
```

Notice you have AND operator twice in a row.

```
where  ENQ.FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID = FOL.FOLLOW_TYPE_ID(+) and ENQ.PRIORITY_ID = PRI.PRIORITY_ID(+) and ENQ.ACTIVITY_ID = ACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) and ENQ.NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID = NACT.ACTIVITY_ID(+) AND enq.flat_id = flt.flat_id(+) and enq.ATTENDED_BY_MKEY = em.USER_ID(+) and cef_mkey=2590  order by enq.followup_sr_no desc
```

This is what the line should be.

Also, if you used ANSI-92 instead of ANSI-89 syntax (JOINs instead of all tables in FROM statement), you probably would not get this error because you'd only have one condition in WHERE clause.